# How to convert a path to a CGAL structure

Tags: cgal

Given a path composed of the following statements:

1. moveto
2. lineto
3. closepath

How would you convert a path to a list of `CGAL::Polygon_with_holes_2`?

To be more concrete. The path may be the output of the linearization of the outlines of a string of glyphs. Consider e.g. the text string "xo" turned into a such a path. This will result in 3 disjoined closed polygon:

1. A counterclockwise polygon corresponding to the "x"
2. A counter clockwise (almost circular) polygon corresponding to the "o"
3. A clockwise (also almost circular, but smaller) path corresponding to the hole in "o"

If I understand the documentation of CGAL correctly this may be stored in CGAL as two `CGAL::Polygon_with_holes2`. But how do you you construct these given the path with the three polygons as described above? Is there a convenience function for this or do I have to check for cross intersection of all path polygons?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [following constructor](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon/classCGAL_1_1Polygon__with__holes__2.html#adc3d686732eefb6ee3768905d0a4d8f9) that takes the outer boundary polygon (which must be counterclockwise oriented) and the range of holes (that are also `Polygon_2` object but clockwise oriented).

You can construct a [`Polygon_2`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon/classCGAL_1_1Polygon__2.html#a70f472d2a157796924224fd7c7002884) using a range of 2D points.

Comment: Yes, but that does't solve the problem of how to automize the calculation of which clockwise contours are holes to which counterclockwise polygons.

Comment: You can use the function [`bounded_side()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon/classCGAL_1_1Polygon__2.html#aff9f5e227e90bb285c7b3fbd8cb23369) with one point of a polygon to know about the nesting. The way to proceed is to take the polygon with the small contour point (lexicographically speaking) and then check if the other one are contained. You can filtering then using their bounding boxes to be faster. Of course this assumes that polygons are disjoint.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that I have enough info to write something up. I guess that what I was hoping for, a ready made "list of polygons" → (a smaller) "list of polygons-with-holes" was wishing too much.

Comment: Actually I wrote it in [3D](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__orientation__grp.html#ga133e58280959c152770525f27bb42b91) for triangle meshes.

Comment: Perhaps this is my chance of making a contribution to CGAL for the 2D case. :-)